# How to pass parameter to get_queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have Django API built in and I have endpoint the return all object. I want the user to provide me with keyword to filter this queryset. What is the best way to do it. and how to do it plz ?

is it in get_queryset? if yes can you help me !?

Comment: As URL parameter? GET parameter? POST parameter?

Comment: yes ... only in GET method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have access to the GET parameters (in the *querystring*) with [**`self.request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).

So for example if there is a parameter `?category=foo`, you can access foo with `self.request.GET['category']`, or `self.request.GET.get('category')` if you want it to return `None` in case it is missing.

You thus can filter for example with:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from app.models import SomeModel
from app.serializers import SomeSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = SomeModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        category = self.request.GET.get('category')
        if category is None:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(category=categry)
```

Answer (score 0):

just give pass the parameter with some default value:

```
def get_queryset(self, some_thing=default):
        .
        .
        .
```

It will work